# Iterating over datetime objects?

Tags: python, web2py

I want to implement a scheduling conflict finder among inputed forms. Each entry has a date time field called `start_time`. My approach is to create two empty dictionaries, order the loop in order of earliest time, and pass each `start_time` field through a check if that value is in the first empty dictionary. If not, it is updated into that first dictionary. If it is, that is a conflict and its added to the second dictionary.

I have gotten the error 'datetime.datetime object is not iterable'.

```
def checker():
    d1 = dict()
    d2 = dict()
    for task in db().select(db.database.ALL, orderby=db.database.start_time):
        if not task.start_time in d1:
            d1.update(task.start_time)
        else:
            d2.update(task.start_time)
    return dict(d1=d1, d2=d2)
```

However this returns the error that `datetime.datetime` is not iterable. Is there a way to change the `datetime` objects into strings or tuples and iterate over those, then change it back to a `datetime` and add it to the dictionary it need to go to?

Comment: `.update()` requires a complete dictionary as an argument, not just a value.  And if you know you're just setting a single value, it's silly to even use `update()`.  Just assign the dict key as normal, i.e. `d1['somekey'] = task.start_time`

Comment: Hmm, it seems like you're using d1 and d2 more like lists or sets, not dicts...